# Unhandled Java exception execute remainder of method?

Tags: java, exception

I was responding to a slough of basic Java practice test questions and the correct answer to the following question slipped past me while taking the test.

Question:  "If an exception is not caught, the finally block will run and the rest of the method is skipped - TRUE or FALSE?"

I am attempting to prove out the answer with the ThrowTest class (pasted at bottom) but I find Java exception handling to be somewhat unfamiliar.  I compile the class as is with the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException portion of the catch block commented out.  I then execute the class without passing an input parm thus creating an exception (the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) .  I would expect the final System.out.println would not execute and indeed it does not.

I find if I un-comment the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException catch block and recompile, the class then catches that specific error at run time and executes the "Rest of method" println at bottom.    So, does my code prove the rest of "the rest of the method is skipped" or do I have to test it from a method other than the main method? Maybe there is a more straightforward method of testing it.

```
public class ThrowTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try
        {
            String anyString = args[0];
            System.out.println("Try  code executes");
        }

    catch(SecurityException e)  //any old exception
        {
            System.err.println ("Error: SecurityException. ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    /* begin comment
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: Caught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. ");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    end comment */

    finally
        {
            System.out.println("finally block executes!");  
        }

        System.out.println("Rest of method executes!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what exception is thrown a `finally` block will always execute (barring any strange situations like out of memory), so given the following

```
try {
  // do some code
}
catch (SomeException e) {
  // exception handling
}
finally {
  doFinallyStuff();
}

doOtherStuff();
```

`doFinallyStuff` will always execute here. But `doOtherStuff` will only execute under the following conditions:

- No exceptions are thrown
- `SomeException` is thrown and the catch block does not rethrow the exception up the chain

If another exception is thrown in the `try` block that is not handled by the `catch` block, `doFinallyStuff` will still execute, but `doOtherStuff` will not

Answer (score 0):

Your code is indeed proving that everything works as you described. When you catch an exception, then the rest of the method thereafter executes. If you let the method throw the exception, its execution halts immediately. Either way, the finally block will always execute.

Comment: Thank you StrixVaria and Veger for the quick answers yesterday!